# What is wrong with my code? Supposed to validate credit number using Luhn algorithm

Tags: c++, luhn

My code is supposed to validate credit cards using Luhns algorithm, defined as follows:

> Counting from the check digit, which is the rightmost, and moving left, double the value of every second digit.
> Sum the digits of the products (e.g., 10: 1 + 0 = 1, 14: 1 + 4 = 5) together with the undoubled digits from the original number.
> If the total modulo 10 is equal to 0 (if the total ends in zero) then the number is valid according to the Luhn formula; else it is not valid.

There is an issue somewhere in the loop where I assign values to `num[]`, which should be the individual digits of `cc`. Could also be issues elsewhere, but I'm pretty sure it works. `cc%x` and `cc%y` are returning incorrect values. I also tried using `pow()` instead of my own `exp`, because I thought that may have been the problem as it returns a different data type, but it was not working either.

My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int exp(int , int);

int main()
{
    int cc;
    int x, y;
    int sum  = 0;
    cout<<"Enter your credit card number\n";
    cin>>cc;
    int num[16];
    int digO[8];
    int digE[8];
    //Get digits of CC
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        x = exp(10, i+1);
        y = exp(10, i);
        cout<<endl<<"X, Y: "<<x<<", "<<y;
        num[i]= (cc%x - cc%y)/exp(10, i);
        int check = cc%x;
        int check2 = cc%y;
        cout<<"\nCheck1: "<<check<<endl<<"Check2: "<<check2;
        
    }
    //Get odd digits of CC
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        x = 2*(i+1)-1;
        digO[i] = num[x];
    }
    //Luhn algorithm: mult digit by 2
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        digO[i] = 2*digO[i];
    }
    //Add each digit of product
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + (digO[i]%100 - digO[i]%10)/10 + digO[i]%10;
    }
    //Get even digits
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        x = (2*i);
        digE[i] = num[x];
    }
    //Add sum + even digits
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + digE[i];
    }
    //Check if last digit of sum is 0
    bool checkSum = (sum%10 ==0);
    if (checkSum)
    {
        cout << "Valid credit card number." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid credit card number." << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

//Exponent function
int exp(int base, int exponent)
{
    int result = 1;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < exponent; i++)
    {
        result *= base;
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You have made this far, FAR more complicated than it needs to be.  You can split off the digits one by one in a loop by doing `digit = num % 10;` / `num = num / 10;`.  None of the exponentiation stuff is required.

Comment: However, the BIGGEST problem you have is that a 16-digit number does not fit into a 32-bit `int`.  You have an overflow.  You'll either need to read it into a `long` or read it as a string.

Comment: @TimRoberts "*You'll either need to read it into a `long` ...*" - `long` is not guaranteed to be larger than an `int`. Use `long long` or better `int64_t` instead

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'd use `std::intmax_t` for signed integers where user input is to be concidered, but ...  I don't think that's where the major problem is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: About using `std::exp` you will get rounding errors due to floating point imprecissions

Comment: *"but I'm pretty sure it works"* -- When a bug resists initial attempts at debugging, this phrase means "80%-90% chance the bug is here". Don't guess. Create a [mre] showing definitively where the problem lies. -- *"`cc%x` and `cc%y` are returning incorrect values"* -- This tells me you need at most three lines of code to demonstrate the error: one to initialize `cc` to an appropriate value, one to initialize `x` to an appropriate value, and one to stream `cc%x` to the standard output.

Answer (score -3):

Here is a much simpler way of handling this.  Because the repeated mod 10 operations here strip off the digits starting from the right, we can do the summation on the fly.  We don't need to hold all of the digits first.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int64_t cc;

    cout<<"Enter your credit card number\n";
    cin>>cc;
    
    // Pull off the check digit.

    int card = cc % 10;
    int sum = 0;
    cc /= 10;

    for( int i = 0; i < 15; i++ )
    {
        // Grab the next digit.
        int digit = cc % 10;
        cc /= 10;

        // For every other digit, double it.
        if( i % 2 )
        {
            digit *= 2;
            if( digit >= 10 )
                digit = (digit / 10) + (digit % 10);
        }
        sum += digit;
    }

    // Check our number against the card.
    int chk = 10 - (sum % 10);
    cout << "Computed " << chk << endl;
    cout << "Card " << card << endl;
}
```

Comment: Because it takes a one-line change to make it work on Windows.  There, I fixed it.

Comment: Also try to show examples without `using using namespace;` . If you want to know why watch this "C++ weekly" episode : [stop using using namespace](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZqjl9HEPZ8). Also good code uses functions and doens't put anything in one main (e.g. the moment you have to type a comment is the moment you should make a function with a name that is selfdescribing and move the corresponding code into that function). In your case that function would be `std::uint64_t double_every_other_digit(digit);`

Comment: There is a wide spectrum between guiding a person from their code towards a solution, and providing a complete best-practices replacement.  That seems to have been lost here.